# How to make a custom dialog transparent?

Tags: android, dialog

I need to make my custom dialog transparent.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please show that you have made some effort? Any example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hey budy. . .  Use the xml file for Background that in Available in the developer site and Set #00000000 as the Background colour thats for the Transperent colour.

Comment: For some reason you can run into graphical glitches if you use `#00000000`.  I recommend using `@android:color/transparent`.  Don't ask me why since they are the same ARGB value, just trust me that I have run into problems with it.

Comment: @Styler where would I add this `@android:color/transparent` line? in the xml-file for the dialog or in a style? been trying `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` but I suspect Im not doing it right. Mostly since its not working ^^

Answer (score 10):

You can also use following line in constructor

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the background of the Dialog transparent you just need to set the theme of dialog to be **android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar**. eg:-

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set background color to Color.Transparent

Comment: to setBackgroundDrawable you would need a ColorDrawable and in this case @Tarun Nagpal has the correct way of doing this.