# Custom Transparent Dialog (windowBackground non-existant?)

Tags: android, xml, dialog, transparent

I'm attempting to create a custom dialog with a semi transparent background. I managed to get it to work through code with:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.bg_tran);
```

Where bg_tran == #A0000000. However I'd rather have it in XML as I use this for several different custom dialog classes. Using just android:background does not work. Nor setting the theme to @android:style/Theme.Translucent worked.

I found several articles talking about using the attribute android:windowBackground.  However the android:windowBackground attribute does not exist. Meaning eclipse doesn't show me it as an option for auto complete.  I've checked within my style sheet and my actual layout.xml. Since I'm compiling for 2.2 I thought that the issue and changed build target to 4.0.3.  No fix.  I've even tried explicitly using it anyway but it doesn't work. I searched the Android Dev website and can't even find the page which describes this attribute. Aside from occasionally mentioning in passing, there's nothing. Also looking up setBackgroundDrawableResource doesn't tell me what the equivalent XML attribute tag is. I'm incredibly confused.  What am I missing?

Stack overflow references I used to learn above:
[Transparent Dialog Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070505/android-how-to-create-a-transparent-dialog-themed-activity)
[Android Dialog Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059068/android-dialog-transparent)
[How to make a custom dialog transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580531/how-to-make-a-custom-dialog-transparent)

**Update:**
In case it wasn't clear, yes I've tried setting this up within a theme. Does not work. Here's my defined theme:

```
<style name="my_dialog_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bg_tran</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Why are you not using it as a theme? you can set this theme to all your dialogs..

Comment: I am. Updated my question to reflect

Comment: I have used `android.R.style.Theme_Panel` when instantiating the `Dialog`.  In the XML I used a custom `Drawable` as the background to do the white outline with rounded corners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a custom theme for your dialog.

```
<style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    ...
    ...
</style>
```

### Update:

You can achieve what you want in your dialog by extending the `Dialog` class. Set the window background drawable in this derived class.

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog 
{
    public CustomDialog (final Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        // This is the layout XML file that describes your Dialog layout
        this.setContentView(R.layout.myDialogLayout);  
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.bg_tran);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already am. The issue is that windowBackground is not working. Updated question to show my theme.

Comment: try adding `WindowIsTranslucent` too to the theme.should work.

Comment: Nope. Still not working. Where are you finding these tags? Cause none of these window* attributes are appearing as available options. Is there some magical list of all xml attributes?

Comment: Did you not read my question? The first thing I said was that I already got it to work through code by using the getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource() method.  That's not the issue. I'm trying to get it through XML only.

Comment: And you want to make the solution scalable.. right..? Why only through xml method?

Comment: Separation of functionality and design. I do not want to always call the setBackground method in code everytime I use that layout.

Comment: Okay.. dont set the layout in `CustomDialog`. Set it in your class derived from this `CustomDialog` but apply all needed properties in this `CustomDialog`'s constructor..

Comment: yeeaahhhh. Thought about doing that as a backup. Guess that means its not possible thru XML only

Comment: Its possible using xml by using `<style>`. Dont know why it doent work in your case..

Comment: Would you acccept this as answer?

Comment: make sure theme DOES NOT have <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue. android:windowBackground attribute just does not appear.you have to type the attribute complete and correct yourself then build your project. Voila, it will compile without any errors and it will work perfectly.