# How to set Transparent Background as a Custom Dialog Box in android

Tags: android, dialog

I need to make my custom dialog box as a transparent.

Sample Code :

```
Dialog dialog;
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{ 
    switch(id) 
    {
        case 1:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = null;
            Context mContext = this;
            LayoutInflater inflater = ( LayoutInflater ) mContext.getSystemService( LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            View layout = inflater.inflate( R.layout.about_page, ( ViewGroup ) findViewById( R.id.about_Root ) );
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( mContext );
            builder.setView( layout );
            dialog = builder.create();
            break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

How do set Transparent Dialog Box.

My XML Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/about_Root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/alert_page_border"
    android:orientation="vertical" >        
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/about_Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:text="Welcome" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code Alert_page_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">     
    <solid android:color="#3b3b3b" />
    <stroke 
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />
    <padding 
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" /> 
    <corners 
        android:radius="2dp" />     
</shape>
```

Sample Screenshot :

[image]

How do avoid this block color.

Comment: My AndroidManifest.xml file Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: I have added this code `android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"` to my AndroidManifest.xml File.

Answer (score 52):

Use dialog instead of AlertDialog

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.splash);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Width of dialog is fit to the screen.Is there is any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

If you are on API >= 11, you can try to set a theme to your Dialog like that :

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext , android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Or you can try to set the background transparent :

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create a style and apply that to your dialog

```
    <style name="myDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/Transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Then, create your Dialog by using this theme;

```
    Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.myDialogTheme) {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.about_page);
        }
    };
```

Hope this will help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: Midhu I already referred to apply this code. This code is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

add the code above after this line.

```
View layout = inflater.inflate( R.layout.about_page, ( ViewGroup ) findViewById( R.id.about_Root ) );
```

Comment: userIsAMonkey I got the same Screen Shot.

Comment: So you have to try Midhu's answer just below by applying style to your Dialog (you will have to drop the use of the builder though)

Comment: Sorry! Edited it, it's setBackgroundDrawable, but it is depreciated in Jelly Bean.

Comment: Plumillon is right. I used the above code using my Activity as a Themed dialog.

Comment: userIsAMonkey I have already change your Code `layout.setBackgroundDrawable` to workout my example. I got the Same Screen Shot.

Answer (score 1):

This question of yours describes exactly what my problem was. I tried every single solution I stumbled upon in this thread as well as in several more threads. Nothing worked. Finally I stumbled upon [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10484888/1108032) and the [corresponding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10485055/1108032).

I had to create a custom dialog class. So I did and it worked. Actually the following styles were sufficient for me:

`colors.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="transparent_black">#66000000</color>
</resources>
```

`styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="custom_dialog_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_black</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The code of the dialog class:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;

import my.app.com.android.R;

public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
    public AddBookCustomDialog(final Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.custom_dialog_theme);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.add_book_dialog);
    }
}
```

And how I use this dialog in the activity code:

```
CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog(this);
customDialog.show();
```

I don't know why I have to create a custom class in order for the theme to be taken into account. Now I have achieved what I wanted to do: transparent dialog. The next fight will be to position positive and negative buttons as long as I can no longer user the convenience methods of `AlertDialog.Builder`. Hopefully my code will prove of help to you.

Also notice the low value of alpha - maybe even try it with 00 so that you make sure whether your configuration works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null)` to remove the default background.

Here is the doc for reference:

> ```
> /*** Set the background to a given Drawable, or remove the background. If the
>    * background has padding, this View's padding is set to the background's
>    * padding. However, when a background is removed, this View's padding isn't
>    * touched. If setting the padding is desired, please use
>    * {@link #setPadding(int, int, int, int)}.
>    *
>    * @param d The Drawable to use as the background, or null to remove the
>    *        background
>    */
> ```

Comment: You are the bomb mate ! This worked fantastically :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/a"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#00000000">

 <!-- Write your LinearLayout code here -->

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Try this code.

Comment: Krishna I got the same Problem after modified the XML Code.

Comment: Set height and width of your layout. Set its gravity

Comment: This didn't work for me... I get a greyish back color.

Answer (score 0):

just remove

from Alert_page_border.xml

Comment: remove <stroke 
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />